# JavaScript Store operations in variable ? Is it possible

Tags: javascript, variables, math

Hello I have one code that performs an operation and show the result. Is it possible to store half operation in a variable and use it dynamically.?

Example

```
 result = (((Math.pow((1045.34/1000), (1/(18/12)))) -1)*4/3)*100;
```

I want to store "*4/3" in a variable and apply them like

```
 var oper = "*4/3"
 result = (((Math.pow((1045.34/1000), (1/(18/12)))) -1)oper)*100;
```

ANy idea How to achieve this ?

Comment: `var result = function(a,b){return ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eval() function

```js
var toto = "4/3";

alert(eval(toto));
```

Comment: I know that's a bad idea but if he really wants to do this, it's the unique easier solution

Comment: It's a terrible solution. If they really want it - we're here to tell them "DO NOT"

Answer (score 2):

Use a function?

```
function doStuff(stuff) {
    return stuff * 4 / 3;
}

var result = doStuff(((Math.pow((1045.34/1000), (1/(18/12)))) -1)) * 100;
```

Here we pass `((Math.pow((1045.34/1000), (1/(18/12)))) -1)` into our `doStuff()` function, and that returns the result of that multiplied by 4 and divided by 3. We can then multiply it by 100 (as your question does).

`result` ends up with the value:

```
-> 4.000365122980623
```

Comment: I failed miserably trying to find matching parentheses PS: yep, I know you just took OP's expression, but still... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `eval` function.

```
result = eval('(((Math.pow((1045.34/1000), (1/(18/12)) -1)' + oper + ')*100;');
```

Be careful though, `eval` can be dangerous. Check [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/) if you want to know why.